# Get product collection filter by if attribute exists?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, product-collection, collection-filtering

**Goal: Retrieve a collection of products that have a certain attribute**

Here's what I'm trying:

```
public function Hydrate($attribute)
{
    $this->id = Mage::helper('myHelper')->CamelCase($attribute->getFrontendLabel());
    $this->name = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(),array('like' => '%%'))
        ->load();

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        array_push($this->collection,Mage::getModel('myModels/Json_Product')->Hydrate($product));
    }



    return Mage::helper('myHelper')->ConvertToJson($this);
}
```

It's working.  However, **I was just wondering if that addFieldToFilter() is going to have any repercussions that I can't currently see?**

Magento 1.9.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIKE` is not the most performant choice. Since `%%` (which is equivalent to `%`) matches every string, even empty strings, you probably want to check if the field is `NOT NULL`.

The right filter parameter in this case is:

```
    ->addFieldToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(),array('notnull' => true))
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value) you can see a protected question about this showing how to perform what you need.

Basically using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');  
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('orig_price');    

//filter for products whose orig_price is greater than (gt) 100
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'orig_price','gt'=>'100'),
));
```

should do the trick.